# python3.6 ffmpeg call MacOSX (closed)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm using Python 3.6 on MacOSX. I would like to use FFmpeg as Python sub-process. Everything works fine when using the OSX embedded Python 2.7 but using 3.6, this doesn't work.

I get an error message because it doesn't find FFmepg:

```
raise FFExecutableNotFoundError("Executable '{0}' not found".format(self.executable))
ffmpy.FFExecutableNotFoundError: Executable 'ffmpeg' not found
```

I tried with ffmpy but I also got the same result by invoking FFmpeg directly:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["ffmpeg"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    call(["ffmpeg"])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
```

I installed the FFmpeg lib. by using Brew through Terminal. It was well installed but only visible by Python 2.7, not 3.6.

Calling it from terminal is working :

```
$ ffmpeg

ffmpeg version 3.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
```

I'm not (yet) a Linux specialist but I think that a path is missing for 3.6 to find FFmpeg.

Any clue to solve this annoying issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run ffmpeg on Terminal MacOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243426/run-ffmpeg-on-terminal-macos)

Comment: Maybe try using the absolute path to the `ffmpeg` binary that you want.

Comment: Thx for your answer. It works now. You're right, I just added the real FFmpeg location when calling it.

Comment: I don't see it as a duplicate, but here is a closely related question, except for Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798198/oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-converting-mp3

Answer (score 0):

Your particular issue was solved, but let me share how I solved the same error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'
```

Anybody's first reaction would be to check whether `ffmpeg` was installed properly in the relevant environment. In my case, I had run `conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg` *without error messages*. When I ran `find / -name ffmpeg`, I found the `ffmpeg` directory located where I expected it to be, that is `/Users/PatrickT/miniconda3/envs/sp/bin/ffmpeg`. The version was `ffmpeg-4.2.2`. I ran `conda search ffmpeg --channel conda-forge` and found an update was available, so I installed it again, but this time using a slightly different syntax, just in case:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install ffmpeg
```

And this time it worked!

Conclusion: For whatever reason `ffmpeg` had not been installed properly on my system and while the `ffmpeg` directory had been created in the right place, invoking the application failed. In short, the problem was exactly as the error message stated: `No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg'`